# DQL Query Using Variable in Select Statement Returning Exception

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I am getting this Exception:

[Semantical Error] line 0, col 124 near 'column = :column': Error: 'column' is not defined.

When trying to run this code:

```
/**
 * @param User $user
 * @param String $column
 * @return array
 */
public function getStatsByDQL(User $user, String $column)
{
    $midNight = date_create('00:00:00')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $em2 = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:ExerciseStats')
        ->createQueryBuilder('g')
        ->setParameters(array(
            'user' => $user, 'column' => $column, 'date' => $midNight,
        ))
        ->where('user = :user', 'g.timestamp < :date',  'column = 
:column')
        ->select('g.column')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->join('g.user', 'user')
        ->orderBy('g.column','DESC')

        ->getQuery()->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
        return $em2;
```

Here's how it is executing:

```
$yy = $this->getStatsByDQL($usr, 'bench_press_1_weight');
    var_dump($yy);
```

This DQL Query runs fine when 'g.column' is replaced by 'bench_press_1_weight', but goes awry when g.column is placed there instead. I *think*  'bench_press_1_weight' should be passed since I set in parameters 'column' => $column. To me, this should work. I have not found the Doctrine docs to be of any use and have tried a myriad of combinations.

This function is in my default controller.

Anyone have any clues? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you actually have a database table column named column?  Column is a reserved word in mysql so that won't end well.

Comment: Actually I don't have a column named column, if you look at the code, you'll see it's the variable name. This is DQL, and not SQL, so I am safe there. Just to be on the safe side I tested it with another variable name, and it made no difference, same exact error message.

Comment: DQL is converted to SQL so the same restrictions apply.  'column = :column' strongly implies a column named column as does the error message.  Are you trying to specify the actual column dynamically?  I guess I am just not understanding the design.  dump($qb->getQuery()->getSQL() will show the generated sql.

Comment: I have 50 columns to get data from, hence the use of the variable. I have changed the variable from column to be on the safe side, fyi (same exact error message coming up). So, I want to use consts to place into the call (where 'bench_press_1_weight' would be a const. By the by, bench_press_1_weight is one of the columns in the database (with about 50 others like it, which need to each be individually called at different times). Hope that clarifies things. Thanks.

Comment: So change ->select('g.column') to ->select('g.' . $column) and do the same for orderby.  And drop the column stuff from the where statement completely.

Comment: I did that, but then got this: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 7 near 'gbench_press_1_weight': Error: 'gbench_press_1_weight' is not defined.  Looks like the 'g' got appended to my actual column name. But at least it got past this function, and now is throwing error at the $yy variable, so I removed the 'g' and just left the quotes blank, and same error message just without the g appended.

Comment: I also removed the quotes all together but the same error occured.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145329/discussion-between-bill-wagner-and-cerad).

Comment: Might be time to take a break and try a fresh approach.  Looks like you are in random mode.  Rewrite the query and just hard code bench_press_1_weight.  Get the query working then add in your column variable stuff.  Maybe even write your query in sql and execute from the command line.  If you don't understand why 'gbench...' is wrong then you need to go back to sql basics.

Comment: I do know why 'gbench is wrong-- the 'g' got appended to bench--when I remove the g, it is not part of the error any more. Anyway, the code works without the variable just fine, when the variable gets added, it all goes to shit. Thanks anyway for trying. Have a good one.

Comment: @BILLWAGNER you probably wrote select('g'.$column) instead of select('g.'.$column) (notice the dot inside the quote)

Comment: Yeah I've tried that too, and it just gives me another error--for some reason it appends the 'g' to what's stored in the variable, saying it's not defined. It seems like there's a piece of doctrine is missing. I am searching for possible missing use statement now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue, it was so simple that I almost shot myself. So what needed to occur was removing the variable introduced in the signature of the function from the params and WHERE statement, and it looks like this:

```
public function getStatsByDQL(User $user,  String $col)
{

    $midNight = date_create('00:00:00')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $parameters = (array('user' => $user, 'date' => $midNight, 

    ));
    $em2 = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:ExerciseStats')
        ->createQueryBuilder('g')
        ->setParameters($parameters)
        ->where('g.user = :user', 'g.timestamp < :date')
        ->select('g.'. $col)
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->join('g.user', 'user')
        ->orderBy( 'g.'. $col,'DESC')
        ->getQuery()->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
    return $em2;
}
```

This returns the correct data I was after, i.e. the column requested and it's contents. Thanks for everyone's input. Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this

```
    ->setParameters(array(
        'user' => $user, 'column' => $column, 'date' => $midNight,
    ))
    ->where('user = :user', 'g.timestamp < :date',  'column = :column')
```

with

```
    ->where('user = :user', 'g.timestamp < :date',  'column = :column')
    ->setParameters(array(
        'user' => $user, 'column' => $column, 'date' => $midNight,
    ))
```

Comment: I've done that and it doesn't change anything. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this

```
->setParameters(array(
    'user' => $user, 'column' => $column, 'date' => $midNight,
))
->where('user = :user', 'g.timestamp < :date',  'column = :column')
```

With this

Try to change this

```
->setParameters(array(
    'user' => $user, 'column' => $column, 'date' => $midNight,
))
->where('g.user = :user', 'g.timestamp < :date',  'g.column = :column')
```

Comment: I get this when I do what you suggested: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 142 near 'column = :column ORDER': Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\ExerciseStats has no field or association named column